# How to implement the Rule of Zero with unique_ptr

Tags: c++, pointers, unique, rules, zero

I actually want to do a example of Rule of Zero with an unique_ptr on a class.
This is my sample code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

// Rule of zero?
template <class T>
class myStruct
{
    int m_timesToPrint{0};
    std::unique_ptr<T> m_ptr;

public:
    myStruct(int tToPrint, const T& val)
    : m_timesToPrint(tToPrint), m_ptr(std::make_unique<T>(val))
    { }

    myStruct() = default;
    myStruct(const myStruct&) = default;

    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const myStruct<T>& rhs)
    {
        for(auto i = 0; i < rhs.m_timesToPrint; ++i)
        {
            os << *(rhs.m_ptr.get()) << "\n";
        }
        os << "---------------\n";
        return os;
    }
};



int main()
{
    myStruct<int> m1(3, 3);
    // myStruct<int> m2 = m1; // Error!

    std::cout << m1;
    // std::cout << m2;

    return 0;
}
```

Obviously, i have a problem on m2 = m1 line, because `unique_ptr(const unique_ptr&) = deleted` is deleted, but how can i do that example?

Thanks!

Comment: *but how can i do that example* You can't.  `unique_ptr`'s are not copyable.  If you want your class to be copyable, you need to define the logic for that.

Comment: And what kind of smart pointer should I use?

Comment: Your requirements are conflicting. You can't have both of those fulfilled: you either drop rule of zero requirement, and define the logic for copying `std::unique_ptr`, or drop `std::unique_ptr` requirement, and use something else, instead of it. Do whichever makes more sense in your case.

Comment: Depends on the semantics you want.  Do you want all copies to point to the same thing, or do you want all copies to point to their own object which is a copy?

Comment: I want to copy the pointer value :)

Comment: @Pablo that implies "all copies to point to the same thing", is that correct?

Comment: No, each copy has his own value of the same resource.

Comment: The "rule of zero" **is** "define none of the special member functions". It's *nonsensical* to say "how do I define a copy constructor to follow the rule of zero?"

Comment: Following the rule of zero would make `myStruct` movable, but not copyable

Answer (score 3):

With the rule of zero, even defaulting constructors is unneeded:

```
template <class T>
class myStruct
{
    int m_timesToPrint{0};
    std::unique_ptr<T> m_ptr;

public:
    myStruct(int tToPrint, const T& val)
    : m_timesToPrint(tToPrint), m_ptr(std::make_unique<T>(val))
    { }

    myStruct() = default;
    // myStruct(const myStruct&) = default; // not needed

    // ... other stuff
};
```

> Obviously, i have a problem on `m2 = m1` line, because `unique_ptr(const unique_ptr&) = deleted` is deleted, but how can i do that example?

Well, your rule of zero is implemented correctly. If you want the copy to work, you need a different tool than `std::unique_ptr`.

My suggestion would be to either create a pointer type that copy its resource, or to use `std::shared_ptr` if you want to share the resource instead of copy it.

Such a pointer could look like this:

```
template<typename T>
struct clone_ptr {
    clone_ptr(clone_ptr const& other) : /* initialize `_ptr` with copy */ {}

    clone_ptr(clone_ptr&&) = default;
    clone_ptr& operator=(clone_ptr&&) = default;

    // implement copy assign

    // implement operators

private:
    std::unique_ptr<T> _ptr;
};
```

Comment: I want to copy the resource ;)

Comment: Then use `myStruct(myStruct&&) = default;`

Comment: @Eljay I don't see how defaulting helps